# Transparent BSDF acting weirdly

Tags: materials, transparency, normals

Here's my mesh:
[image]
I was trying to make the faces with inverted normals of the mesh transparent with this:
[image]
It works perfectly most of the time,
[image]
but when I put another object in the hole that clips with the mesh:
[image]
The parts that intersect the object turns black. How do I fix this?

Blend File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18kZt5k9ColGQ_iKz0RmJ1dUUXM-B2dcY/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that I have 2 objects, a cube (1) that is opened and a plane (2) that has the same material as yours (the front will be opaque but the back will be transparent because of the *Geometry > Backfacing*):

[image]

If you intersect the plane with the cube it will let you see the inside of the cube, because of the transparency, but the inside of the cube will still be black because it can't receive any light (if you are inside the cube the plane will appear opaque). So what you see is the shadow inside the cube:

[image]

If I close it you can clearly see the shadow projected by the opaque side and how the inside becomes black:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize that 'backfacing' isn't based on the camera... so is there a way to fix it?